# default URL vs Javascript relative path

Tags: php, url, cakephp

Why does CakePHP producing those URLs

```
<server>/Reporting/OnlineBanking/index/page:1
```

instead of

```
<server>/Reporting/OnlineBanking/index?page=1
```

There are alot of trouble with this using relative paths out of JavaScript for example.

And is there an option to change it?

Comment: Updated, hope that help, if dont please let me know.

Comment: You right with that cutting after slash. I updated with how I enter session_details. Also tried with "postLink" form the FormHelper but the session_id parameter also displayed in the URL. What confusing me like nothing else.

Comment: Confusing because of the format. Normally the parameters are in the url like that "session_details/session_id=XXXXXX&session_id_2=YYYYYY." If they would be like that i wouldnt have that problem with the relative path out of Javascript

Comment: Dude! thats it! :D The Paginator using "named"-Parameters as default too, that makes me get into trouble because I can never fix this problem without changing the paramType of the Pager. You really helped me alot. Write that as an answer so i cant mark it as correct.

Comment: Sorry for that unclear question before, its hard to write a good question without knowing where the problem could come from. Please write your answer out of the last comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Pagination with get parameters

By default, all parameters in CakePHP are named parameters (url fragments like `/foo:bar/`). This also applies, by default, to pagination arguments.

To use get arguments for pagination params - you can do that by [setting appropriate config](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#pagination-with-get-parameters):

```
public $paginate = array(
    'paramType' => 'querystring'
);
```

This will generate urls of the form:

```
/the/url?page=1&limit=10
```

Instead of:

```
/the/url/page:1/limit:10
```

### Specifying urls as `string` is extremely fragile

Previously you mentioned using urls like `get_backend_requests` in javascript.

You will *still* find problems if you do that even using get arguments of pagination. That's because even for the "same" url, the result can be different:

```
/the/url  => /the/get_backend_requests
/the/url/ => /the/url/get_backend_requests
```

Instead - specify urls in javascript as absolute urls:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',                               
    url: "/xyz/get_backend_requests",
    ...
```

If you're app is sometimes (or always) installed in a subfolder, you can account for that with a simple function:

e.g. in your html/layout put:

```
<html>
    ...
    <script>
        function url(url) {
            return <?php 
                $base = rtrim(Router::url('/'), '/'); 
                if ($base) {
                    echo "'$base' + ";
                }
            ?>url;
        }
    </script>
```

Which will output:

```
<html>
    ...
    <script>
        function url(url) {
            return '/subfolder' + url;
        }
    </script>


$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',                               
    url: url("/xyz/get_backend_requests"), // becomes the string "/subfolder/xyz/get_backend_requests"
    ...
```